# How do I programmatically access nodes on a Tree?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a simple problem. I want to give users the ability to drag and drop one or more users from a list of users, `<s:List>`, to a desired company on a tree of companies, `<mx:Tree>`.

I got all the drag and drop code figured out and the Flex application performs as desired, EXCEPT when the application user is dragging the user objects over the company they want them added to, it does not give any kind of visual cue. Looking at the Flex documentation, the only way to give any visual indication of which company the dragged object will be dropped into is to use this in the dragOver event:

```
CompanyTree.showDropFeedback(event);
```

The code above draws an ugly line either above or below the name of the company, which makes it look like it will be dropped above or below the company, which is NOT what I want. It should be clear to the application user that the user they are dragging to the company goes INSIDE the company.

What I want to do is give the company that is the target of the dragOver the 'Highlighted' effect. But here is where I run into a big problem: according to the Flex documentation, as well as the help given my FlashBuilder and the Flex SDK, **there is no way to access individual nodes on a tree!**

What I CAN do in the dragOver event, is get the index of the item the user is being dropped on with this code:

```
var index:int = CompanyTree.calculateDropIndex(event);
```

But what I CAN'T do with that index is use it to access the node directly and either give it the 'highlighted' effect or apply some kind of setStyle call to it to show to the user that it is currently the target of the drop!

What I WANT to be able to do is something like this:

```
var hoveredNode:UIComponent = CompanyTree.Nodes[index];

hoveredNode.setStyle("color",0xFF0000);
```

But it seems I can't because Flex does not seem to give any way to access nodes on a tree. Or am I missing something?

PS Note that I cannot change the CompanyTree's selectedIndex during the dragOver event, since I also have to retain what the moved users old company is.

Answer (score -1):

You are definitely missing a lot !!! Everything is available you just have to look for it (research). I use since years Trees with either nodes which can connect to separate swf. Image file etc. or Trees which show a thumbnail Image when hovering over a node and by selecting showing the full size Image for example. Research is everything and that not just in FLEX4+ yet I have to admit it getting harder and harder to find anything as so many developer have gone to greener & better pastures since ADOBE left them in the cold! regards aktell

Comment: I have been developing in Flex for over a year and literally did days of research to get to the point of asking this question. "Do Research" is not a helpful answer when the question is: "How do I set a variable to a node in a tree that is the target of a drag and drop operation so I can either set it to 'highlighted' or perform a setStyle call on it?". As far as I can tell from reading the documentation from Adobe, as well as looking at EVERY property of the tree component, there is no concept of a tree node object in Flex, only the tree and its dataProvider.